# Can't find any documentation on Excel Formula

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reverse engineer an Excel Worksheet and I found this in a bunch of the cells:
=RandomizationTable![cell number I'm on]
I've googled a bunch and looked in the support forums but haven't seen a thing about it.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

---

[image]

Comment: It's just a link to a cell on a sheet called 'RandomizationTable', which may be hidden.

Comment: The sheet can be also "Very Hidden". See [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1254447/how-to-unhide-very-hidden-worksheet) for more info.

Comment: Rory, make it an answer and I'll give you a check